# PHP/Zend Framework -When to use an event manager vs injecting another dependency

Tags: php, zend-framework, event-handling

I am not sure when to use an event listener over injecting another dependency into my service.

As an example I want to register an user with a class UserService. I'm using the Zend Framework 2.

Saving the user to the database belongs to the UserService, so I would inject a DbTable into the UserService.

For other things like logging or tracking, I would use the event manager.

But how do I decide for something like sending a mail to the user after registration.

What are some points to make such a decision not only for this case.